# Текст кнопки который не вылазит за её рамки

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Как можно реализовать такую кнопку в юнити с динамическим текстом? https://youtu.be/SbnbyyTXyoM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На кнопку необходимо добавить компонент Маска (Mask или RectMask2D, зависит от конкретных требований). и тогда все дочерние объекты не будут отображаться за пределами такой маски.